# Unable to get laravel to work with aws application load balancer

Tags: laravel-5, amazon-elb

I have set up an application load balancer on AWS. I am able to access my site but when I try to log in, I was redirected to a page with the message "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again I try taking out the ALB and the site work normally but when put on ALB then I keep getting the inactivity page.

I am using Laravel 5.5, hosted on ubuntu 16.04

I set my session and cache on database hope it will solve the issues but I still got the same problem. 
I tried to turn off VerifyCsrfToken middleware, I wasn't redirected to the inactivity page but it keeps redirecting me back to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution to my problem. My APP_KEY was different for all 3 servers, therefore, causing the problem. After changing it to the same APP_KEY in the .env then everything is working fine.

Hope this will help anyone who encounters a similar problem.